# Remove the overlapping in headmapgrid series

Tags: lightningchart

I am using scrollingheadmap grid series. It is working fine, but after my X value reach 2048 exactly, I am seeing this behaviour.

[image]

There is a shift on left side and overlap happening in headmap grid series and it looks like vertical line; how can I prevent this? I disabled datacleaning and other stuff, still this behaviour happens.

Comment: Will need to see code + picture of the bugged chart state with axis visible.

Comment: nevermind , I changed my code based on Constant bands..looks like scrollingheatmap released recently.. will implement once it is stable..

Comment: There are several mentions here of a "headmap". Was a "heatmap" meant instead?